# Dynamic tvOS navigation markers

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, avplayeritem

I have successfully built a `AVNavigationMarkersGroup` (consisting of multiple `AVTimedMetadataGroup`s), which I can attach to an `AVPlayerItem` before loading the video into an `AVPlayer`. However, there are two things I have not been able to do, and I wonder if this is possible:

- Dynamically update these markers after playback has started. This could have several reasons, e.g. not wanting to wait for a slow API, or new information becoming available. So far, I have noticed that when I set the `navigationMarkerGroups` property on an `AVPlayerItem` before I play the item, things are fine, but when I set it after the item has started, the whole app crashes.
- Attach artwork that is loaded via URL. Building an `AVMetadataItem` with the `.commonIdentifierArtwork` identifier is seemingly only possible with raw data, meaning I would have to wait for ALL artwork to completely download before I can build the markers. This would be especially problematic if markers have to be defined before playback starts.

Am I missing something, or are these limitations intended?